# P(x) is x-special???

Tags: set-theory

Beforehand, I apologize for my complete inability to write any sort of TeX commands; fortunately, my question shouldn't require this. (If anyone knows a good reference for me to start learning, I would greatly appreciate it.)  Also, any occurrence of "0" below refers to the empty set.

I'm reading Smullyan and Fitting's "Set Theory and the Continuum Problem," and the authors are trying to show that for a fixed progressing function g, (i.e., a function $g$ on the universal class $V$ such that $x$ is a subset of $g(x)$ for all $x$ in $V$) the existence of the class of all $g$-sets ($x$ is a $g$-set if $x$ belongs to every class superi-nductive under $g$) is derivable without the axiom of substitution.  In particular, when $g$ is the successor function $x \rightarrow x \cup \{x\}$ , this shows that the class of all ordinals exists.

Now, the authors approach this through a series of lemmas.  First, they define:

For sets $S$ and $x$, "$S$ is closed (under $g$) relative to $x$" iff for all $z$ in $S$, if $z$ is a subset of $ x$, then $g(z)$ is in $S$.

A set $S$ is "$x$-special" iff $\emptyset$ is in $S$, $S$ is closed relative to $x$, and $S$ is closed under chain unions.

Then they write "Lemma $7.4$: $P(x)$ is $x$-special. Proof: Obvious."

But I don't believe that's even true! For example, if we let $x = 0$ and $g$ be the successor function, then $P(x) = \{0\} = 1$, so if we take $z = 0$, we see that $z$ is in $S$, $z$ is a subset of $x$, and clearly $g(z) = \emptyset \cup {\emptyset} = {\emptyset} = 1$ is not in $P(x)$, so that $P(x)$ is NOT closed under $g$ relative to $x$, hence, $P(x)$ is NOT $x$-special.

Am I misunderstanding something? Please help clarify this for me...it's been driving me crazy.  It seems so simple, yet I can't understand why the authors would write something like this if it were so "obviously" false.

Thank you!  (Sorry for the long read)

Comment: [Mathjax basic tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It does seem obviously false under these definitions. I would carefully reread the relevant definitions, in particular the definition of closed rel. $x$.

Comment: One guess is that in the definition of closed rel. x, you need $z$ to be a *proper* subset of $x$.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good thought, but the lemma still wouldn't hold. (We could take x = {0,1}, then consider the successor of {1} from P(x).)  I've re-read the relevant sections of this book many times, to no avail. I think I'm going to find a better book. (This isn't the first time I've encountered an issue like this.) Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jrx But first, if you have not done so already, take a look at the errata: http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/fitting/errata/errata.html

Answer (score 5):

I took a look at the [errata](https://id144254.securedata.net/melvinfitting/errata/book_errors/RevisedSetBookErrors/RevisedSetCorrections.pdf) for the 2010 Dover edition, and found a listing for one of the definitions you provided. It is the Page 66 listing.

I quote:

> Definition 7.1 is incorrect as stated. It should read as follows.
> For any sets $y$ and $x$, we will say that $y$ is *closed (under $g$) relative to $x$* provided, for any
> $z \in y$, if $g(z) \in P(x)$ then $g(z) \in y$.

Using this definition, the lemma is indeed obvious.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that really clears this up!